# Are there any  text editors that center text?

Tags: text-editors

When I open up a <s>Open</s>LibreOffice text, the text shows up more to the center of my screen in a nice page metaphor (with the margins showing up nice and well). A nice side effect of this is that my text is usually in front of me, in the middle of the screen, and not completely to the left of me.

Are there any text editors (not word processors) that use this sort of presentation? Instead of pushing the text completely to the left , giving the text a bit of margin to make it more to the center of the screen (and my attention) ?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: And it depends what kind of text editor - `vim` and `emacs` style console editors or graphical editors like GEdit? But to answer your question - no, probably not.

Comment: I use Windows and Linux about equally. As to the kind of editor.... I would rather have a more graphical editor like GEdit, but I can handle console editors pretty well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, Vim can do something similar with [**VimRoom**](http://projects.mikewest.org/vimroom/).

[image]

Additionally, you could make your "margins" more noticable with *set colorcolumn=col1, col2, col3, ...*

Comment: Yeah, you could do this with emacs too, just C-x 3 twice and resize the windows.

Answer (score 1):

You might as well just configure LibreOffice to look like notepad.  It's not going to break the bank memory wise.

[image: LibreOffice]

And the find/replace is a lot better than notepad.

Comment: LibreOffice is NOT a text editor by any stretch of the term. It is a word processor, no matter how much you mess with the graphics.